# backbone-couchdb how to fetch a single model by non-id attrib

Tags: backbone.js, couchdb

I'm using backbone-couchdb. 
I have a lot of functionality working fine. I can create, edit and save models and fetch collections. Now I'm at a place where I need to fetch just a single model by its "tag" attribute. The backbone-couchdb library is setup to do this by "id".

I understand views and keys and filters and everything I need to pull the data from CouchDB manually (with curl) but I don't know how to get just one model by it's "tag" going through backbone-couchdb.

Does this make sense? Have you done this and could you post some help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know backbone-couchdb but I am sure it has [some means for querying views...](http://janmonschke.com/projects/backbone-couchdb.html#custom_views)

Basically what you need to do is

1) Create a view (eg named `by_tag`) that emits the `tag` as the key, such as

```
function(doc)
{
    if(doc.tag)
    {
        emit(doc.tag, null);
    }
}
```

2) Add the view to a design document (say `_design/documents`) and upload it to your database

3) Query your view with some additional parameters:

- `include_docs=true` include the document for which the result was created in the response
- `limit=1` if you only want to retrieve one result
- `key="mytag"` they tag you are interested in

With curl this would be

```
curl http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/documents/_view/by_tag?key=%22mytag%22&include_docs=true&limit=1
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it *can* be done this way via a Backbone "collection" but not with a "model". With backbone-couchdb, you can only do custom attrib fetches through collections, which is normally more than one model, I want to fetch just one model by a "name" attrib. I'm actually doing this in my code using a specially named "SingleCollection" that always returns a single model, but it's kludgy and really should be through model.fetch.

Answer (score 1):

A solution might be to define a model and override the id attribute (set it to tag).
Then you can use a custom view in couchdb to fetch it.

Rg,

Sanne